# DFA in Scheme (homework)

Tags: scheme, racket, dfa

Working on a homework question asking to write a DFA-acceptor in Scheme. Alphabet: {0, 1} Start-state: {Q0} Final-state: {Q2}. String must have a 01 in the sequence to be accepted.
States:
Q0 on 1 transitions to Q1.
Q0 on 0 transitions to Q0.
Q1 on 1 transitions to Q2.
Q1 on 0 transitions to P.
Q2 on 0 and 1 transitions to Q1.
The teacher requested each state to be a function and to return a function that it transitions to. (Q0 1) returns Q1, etc. Code below is an attempt to get things running, before worrying about checking if 01 is in the string. Currently getting an error: "Q0: unbound identifier;" and am not sure why after doing some searching. Any pointers would be helpful. The question is for homework, so not looking for direct answers. Thank you!

```
#lang racket
(define DFA-trans '((Q0 x) (Q1 x) '((Q2 x)) (P x)))

(define x '(1 1 0 1 0))

(define P(null? 1))

(define Q2 (lambda(x)
         (if (null? (car x))
             #t
         (if (equal? (car x) 0)
             (Q2 (cdr x))
         (if (equal? (car x) 1)
             (Q2 (cdr x))
             #t
             )))))

(define Q1 (lambda(x)
         (if (null? (car x))
             #f
         (if (equal? (car x) 0)
             (P (cdr x))
         (if (equal? (car x) 1)
             (Q2 (cdr x))
             #f
             )))))

(define Q0 (lambda(x)
         (if (null? (car x))
             #f
         (if (equal? (car x) 0)
             (Q0 (cdr x))
         (if (equal? (car x) 1)
             (Q1 (cdr x))
             #f
             )))))

(define DFA(map eval DFA-trans))
(DFA)
```

Comment: If it's possible, you should do it without using `eval`. `eval` is not necessary for doing this, and right now it's `eval` that's causing the "unbound identifier" error.

Comment: I was utilizing map eval per the teachers suggestion to tackle the problem. He wants the call to start things off to be: (DFA-Acceptor <list of alphabets in string to be accepted> <start-state> (<list of final states>) <sink-state>). Due to the final state being a list of states (even though it's just Q2), he suggested map eval.

Comment: The issue with `eval` is with mapping the symbols `'Q0`, `'Q1` etc. to the function *values* `Q0`, `Q1` etc, because of namespacing issues. If you can construct the `DFA-trans` list without using quote (`'`), then eval won't give you as much of a problem. For example, instead of `'(Q0 (1 1 0))`, try writing `(list Q0 (list 1 1 0))`.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for your input. I'll play with that for a bit, but am leaning towards your original suggestion of dropping eval. I think I see a solution utilizing most of my current code.

Comment: Does your teacher have a place, either an Office or an online forum, where you can ask questions about these things? Try saying that `eval` isn't working for you, that you're getting "unbound identifier" from even simple programs like `#lang racket (define x 5) (eval 'x)`, and ask if there's a way to do this without using `eval` at all.

Comment: Unfortunately he's unreachable on the weekends and the assignment is due tonight, after having been extended from being due last night due to the difficulty of this problem. I'll be looking for clarification on eval, this upcoming week, from him. I managed to get it working, without eval. Just not sure how in-line it is with what he's asking.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use EVAL for this.

The definitions of P, Q0, Q1, Q2 look good.

If we can define DFA directly, you can just delete DFA-trans.

Assuming Q0 is the start state, I think you can simply do this

```
(define DFA (lambda () (Q0 x)))
```

And consider using COND instead of nested IF.